# Intent.putExtra returns null when used in switch Statement

Tags: java, android, android-intent, null, switch-statement

When passing string using put extra the value is returned `null` on second time on wards.

For example:
 1. User choose case 0, it works as expected.
 2. Then when user choose case 1  it returns `null`.

Now if I try that again and start at 1. Then it works, but then the next case will return `null`. So what I understand is that only in first case it works, no matter what case you choose. From second on wards it fails.

Below switch case is used for option in a menu i have. In next activity data is loaded based on the id passed.

```
Intent intent;
    switch (position) {
        case 0:                 
            intent = new Intent(ChannelActivity.this, ShowsActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("channel_id", "3");
            startActivity(intent);    
            break;
        case 1:            
            intent = new Intent(ChannelActivity.this, ShowsActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("channel_id", "4");
            startActivity(intent);    
            break;
        case 2:                             
            intent = new Intent(ChannelActivity.this, ShowsActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("channel_id", "5");
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        case 3:
            startActivity(new Intent(ChannelActivity.this, ScheduleActivity.class));   
            break;

    }
```

In the next activity class I have the below code in onCreate, its in this activity that am getting null:

```
String channel_id = getIntent().getStringExtra("channel_id");
```

This issue is not there, when the data is passed individually from different functions

Comment: In which Activity getting `Null` ?

Comment: What do you mean when you say "Second time onwards". Plz elaborate. You may give "steps" so that we can try and reproduce your issuue

Comment: I have updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

I tried same type of code and it worked fine for me:

Try following things:

1.Instead of using position in switch case use id of menu items.

2.Put startActivity(intent) below swich statement and remove it from all cases and similarly move your line "intent = new Intent(...) above switch statement".

If these two things don't work then there is problem in other part of your code which you have not pasted.